# Angular : how to call finally() with RXJS 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I was using RXJS 5, now as I upgraded it to 6, I am facing some problems.

Previously I was able to use catch and finally but as per update catch is replaced with catchError (with in the pipe) now how to use finally?

Also I have some questions :

Do I need to change throw->throwError (in below code Observable.throw(err);)

```
import { Observable, Subject, EMPTY, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

return next.handle(clonedreq).pipe(
          catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if ((err.status == 400) || (err.status == 401)) {
            this.interceptorRedirectService.getInterceptedSource().next(err.status);
            return Observable.empty();
        } else {
            return Observable.throw(err);
        }
       }) 
        //, finally(() => {
        //  this.globalEventsManager.showLoader.emit(false);
        //});
      );
```

Also how to use publish().refCount() now ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

- use `throwError` instead of `Observable.throw`, see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#observable-classes
- `finally` was renamed to `finalize` and you'll use it inside `pipe()` among other operators.
- the same with `publish()` and `refCount()`. Both are operators you'll use inside `pipe()`.

Comment: can u pl tell me how to use publish with refcount  in "readonly notification$: Observable<string> = this._notification.asObservable().pipe(publish());"

Comment: `.pipe(publish(), refCount())`

Comment: well since RxJS 6 all operators are functions. Until RxJS 5 operators were methods on the `Observable` class.

Answer (score 34):

Need to import `finalize` from `rxjs/operators`.

`import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Then finalize is used inside the `pipe()`,

```
observable()
    .pipe( 
         finalize(() => {
              // Your code Here
         })
     )
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: finalize has no argument.

Answer (score 2):

[According to official document](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/finalize.html), You should change your code like this to avoid compile error: (You must throw exception in `catchError` method. `finalize` callback method has no argument.)

```
import { catchError, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

return next.handle(clonedreq).pipe(
  catchError(error => {
    console.log('error occured:', error);
    throw error;
  }),
  finalize(() => {
    console.log('finalize')
  })
);
```

It is successfully compiled in `Angular CLI: 7.1.4.`